# How to print 1 to x using ngFor in ionic 3 using multiple ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

> I want to show 0 to user -> terms into a drop-down

Plase check https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-djze7u

**home.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content *ngFor="let item of users">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-label>{{item.name}}:</ion-label>
        <ion-label>{{item.age}}</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="count">
          <ion-option value="0" selected>0</ion-option>
```

> //Here is the problem -> how to make a lopp using ngfor again?
>   //and how to print values of i upto user.terms?

```
 <ion-option ngfor="let i of item.term" value="{{i}}" >
            {{i}}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  users:any = [
    { name: 'Composite Factory', age: 1, term:2 },
    { name: 'Todd', age: 2, term:1 },
    { name: 'Lisa', age: 3, term:4 }
  ];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually ngFor is mistaken please change it to

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content *ngFor="let item of users">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-label>{{item.name}}:</ion-label>
        <ion-label>{{item.age}}</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="count">
          <ion-option value="0" selected>0</ion-option>
          <ion-option *ngFor="let i of  users" [value]="i.term" >
            {{i.term}}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hi Somnath do you want to arrange the terms in ascending order in ion-option

Comment: I want to show 0 to user.item numbers into drop-down

Answer (score 0):

Array name should be `users`. also, use `ngValue` to assign the values.

```
 <ion-option *ngFor="let i of users" [ngValue]="i.term" >
      {{i.term}}
 </ion-option>
```

Comment: @Somnath https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dt8mpw?file=pages/home/home.html

Comment: It is showing only trems value I want to show into drop-down like 0,1,2 or 0,1 or 0,1,2,3,4 this way